# Android Retrofit2 error @Url

Tags: java, android, retrofit

I am having an issue with my Retrofit code, and I seem to be either missing something or not fully understanding what I need done. Here is a full copy of my error.This is my code, why @Url can't use:

```
private interface ApiManagerService {

        //step 1: get car's info link from server
        @GET("v2/link/carillegal")
        Observable<CarInfoUrl> getCarInfoUrl(@QueryMap Map<String, String> params);

        //step 2: get car's info from step 1 link
        @GET
        Observable<String> queryCarInfo(@Url String url);

        //step 3: call back our server with car info from step 2
        @POST("v2/package/carillegal")
        Observable<String> callBackCarInfo(@QueryMap Map<String, String> params, @Body String value);

        ...
    }

Observable.just("1")
                .flatMap(new Func1<String, Observable<CarInfoUrl>>() {
                    @Override
                    public Observable<CarInfoUrl> call(String value) {
                        System.out.println("Observable call1:" + value);
                        return ApiManager.getCarInfoUrl(carInfoArray[0], "2203");
                    }
                })
                .flatMap(new Func1<CarInfoUrl, Observable<String>>() {
                    @Override
                    public Observable<String> call(CarInfoUrl carInfoUrl) {
                        System.out.println("Observable call2:" + carInfoUrl.getLink());
                        return ApiManager.queryCarInfo(carInfoUrl.getLink());
                    }
                })
                ....
                });
```

and throw Exception:

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: HTTP method annotation is required (e.g., @GET, @POST, etc.).
    for method ApiManagerService.queryCarInfo
    at retrofit.Utils.methodError(Utils.java:177)
    at retrofit.Utils.methodError(Utils.java:167)
    at retrofit.RequestFactoryParser.parseMethodAnnotations(RequestFactoryParser.java:135)
    at retrofit.RequestFactoryParser.parse(RequestFactoryParser.java:59)
    at retrofit.MethodHandler.create(MethodHandler.java:30)
    at retrofit.Retrofit.loadMethodHandler(Retrofit.java:151)
    at retrofit.Retrofit$1.invoke(Retrofit.java:132)
    at com.xlzg.wzcx.lib.api.$Proxy0.queryCarInfo(Unknown Source)
    at com.xlzg.wzcx.lib.api.ApiManager.queryCarInfo(ApiManager.java:131)
    at com.xlzg.wzcx.lib.MyClass.main(MyClass.java:24)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:57)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:606)
    at com.intellij.rt.execution.application.AppMain.main(AppMain.java:140)
```

Comment: which beta of retrofit 2 are you using ?

Comment: yes! retrofit 2-beta2

Answer (score 2):

For Retrofit 2 you can set `@GET(".")` to declare that your final URL is the same as your base URL.

Comment: I am really interesting for minuses for this question. Is it better to stay without answers for years? It's a correct answer by the way!

Anybody please try to explain me rules before I will delete the answer and stop making suffering for some reason for someone.